# Why can I access and console.log the key value data from mongdb, but not in ejs file?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm trying to create a page where there are two inputs to query two database collections and then display data in a table and in a title.

The "job" data seems to renders no problem, the "operative" data only displays as a raw object like this:

[image: page display thus far]

If I try to access and inject the "operative" name using `<%= operative.name %>`, I get a "Cannot read property "name" of null."

Here is the express code:

```
app.get('/rounds/new', async(req, res) => {
const { number } = req.query;
const { employee } = req.query;
const round = await Job.find({ roundNumber: number });
const operative = await Operative.findOne({ name: employee });

res.render('rounds/new', { round, operative })
```

});

And this displays the raw object data:

```
<h2><%= operative %></h2>
```

This creates an error:

```
<h2><%= operative.name %></h2>
```

To summarise, I can get the raw "operative" data but I can't access and inject the key values from it without throwing an error. The other "job" one works perfectly.

Whats going on?

EDIT: If it helps...if I click search with `<%= operative %>` in the html page, the raw data displays as usual however if I immediately go to the code editor and change the code to `<%= operative.name %>, save and refresh the page when the data is still being displayed (as seen in the image), it changes to just 'Billy' - the intended result.

Comment: can you `console.log(typeof operative)` and see it's data type? make sure it's accessible as an JS object and not stored in a fancy JSON string

Comment: The typeof is “object”. Any other ideas?

Comment: Weird. I did a small test myself and if it really is an object the view should display this as `[object Object]` and not as literal json string.  Which is the case in my own example. Can you try `<%= JSON.parse(operative).name %> if it displays the name?

Comment: I tried it and got another error: `<h2><%= JSON.parse(operative).name %></h2> 13| 14| Unexpected end of JSON input`